# Statevector formalism,$|\psi\rangle =c_1|A\rangle +c_2|B\rangle \neq (c_1a_1+c_2b_1)|u_1\rangle +(c_1a_2+c_2b_2)|u_2\rangle $

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, superposition

In statevector formalism suppose two particle 
$|\psi\rangle =c_1|A\rangle +c_2|B\rangle $ where $|A\rangle =a_1|u_1\rangle +a_2|u_2\rangle , |B\rangle =b_1|u_1\rangle +b_2|u_1\rangle $, but $|\psi\rangle =c_1|A\rangle +c_2|B\neq (c_1a_1+c_2b_1)|u_1\rangle +(c_1a_2+c_2b_2)|u_2\rangle $.

I'm kind of confused by this expression, because if they are orthonormal states($|u_1\rangle$ ,$|u_2\rangle$ ) , why can't we use superposition principle and add them together? Why can't we expand this expressoin($|\psi\rangle $) into $|u_1\rangle $ and $|u_2\rangle $ by the linearlity of $|u_1\rangle $ and $|u_2\rangle $ ?

Notice: Suppose numbers are all real for simplicity $(c_1a_1+c_2b_1)^2+(c_1a_2+c_2b_2)^2=(c_1a_1)^2+(c_2b_1)^2+2c_1a_1c_2b_1+(c_1a_2)^2+(c_2b_2)^2+2c_1a_2c_2b_2=c_1^2+c_2^2+2c_1a_1c_2b_1+2c_1a_2c_2b_2=1+2c_1a_1c_2b_1+2c_1a_2c_2b_2>1$.

Comment: suppose two particle? I'm confused, did you try to describe 2 particles?

Comment: @OfekGillon Yes. $|\psi>$ is a suposition of particle $|A>$ and $|B>$ normalized  by $c_1,c_2$.  Particle $|A>$  is normalized  with respect to state vector $|u_1>,|u_2>$ by $a_1,a_2$. Particle $|B>$  is normalized  with respect to state vector $|u_1>,|u_2>$ by $b_1,b_2$.

Comment: Why do you normalize two particles? Why do you add them? When having two particles you should use a tensor product

Comment: @OfekGillon It's $|c_1|^2$ portion/probability of particle $A$  and $|c_2|^2$ for particle $B$. The measurement $|A><A|+|B><B|$ obtain either particle $A$ or $B$, yet, if one add them together, the secondary result for measurement $|u_1><u_1|+|u_2><u_2|$ is differed. (Acturally, if you add them together, the sate is no longer normalized)

Comment: What does it mean to have a $|c_1|^2$ probability of a particle? Can you please give an example?

Comment: @OfekGillon Suppose a mixure of $N$ particles with $|c_1|^2 N$ of particle $A$. Or shot single particles with probability of obtian $A$ to be $|c_1|^2$.

Comment: Ok, then that's not a wave function comprised of a quantum superposition

Comment: @OfekGillon what do you mean? $|\psi>=c_1 A+c_2 B$, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_superposition#Theory It's either indistinguishable quantum particles of $A$ or $B$ or a single particle of superposition $A$ and $B$.

Comment: The examples in wikipedia aren't two different particles - it is the same particle with probabilities being in two different states.

Comment: @OfekGillon so the measurement of $|u_1>$ and $|u_2>$ collapse the states into $|A>$ and $|B>$ before the measurement? How could that be? I didn't measure or perform the measurement $|A><A|+|B><B|$..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85248/discussion-between-ofek-gillon-and-user9976437).

Comment: Let me see if I understand your issue here. The problem is that you are adding together two normalized states, but the sum itself is not normalized?

Comment: @AaronStevens Not only they are not normalized, but also the addition is completely wrong. Using Bayes' theorem, the correct solution in real is $\sqrt{c_1^2a_1^2+c_2^2b_1^2}|u_1>+\sqrt{c_1^2a_2^2+c_2^2b_2^2}|u_2>$. The linear sum gave the complete different result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why can't we expand $|\psi\rangle$ into $|u_1\rangle$ and $|u_2\rangle$ by the linearity?

Of course we can. But if you do this, you will not get the expression that you wrote.
$$ c_1 ( a_1 |u_1\rangle + a_2 |u_2\rangle) + c_2 (b_1 |u_1\rangle + b_2|u_2\rangle) = (c_1 a_1 + c_2 b_1) |u_1\rangle + (c_1 a_2 + c_2 b_2) |u_2\rangle . $$

---

**Edit**: The above was an answer to v4 of the question, let me also answer v7.

Note first that you claim $2c_1 a_1 c_2 b_1 + 2c_1 a_2 c_2 b_2 > 0$, which is not true in general.

You write $|\psi\rangle = c_1|A\rangle + c_2 |B\rangle$ and assume $c_1^2 + c_2^2 = 1$. The condition "$c_1^2 + c_2^2 = 1$" is the condition for normalization if, and only if, $|A\rangle$ and $|B\rangle$ are orthogonal, so you should additionally assume
$$\langle A | B \rangle = a_1 b_2 + a_2 b_1 = 0 .$$
Then your calculation shows that $(c_1 a_1 + c_2 b_1)^2 + (c_1 a_2 + c_2 b_2)^2 = 1$ as it should be.

Comment: Sorry, that's an typo but you see, suppose numbers are all real for simplicity $(c_1a_1+c_2b_1)^2+(c_1a_2+c_2b_2)^2=(c_1a_1)^2+(c_2b_1)^2+2c_1a_1c_2b_1+(c_1a_2)^2+(c_2b_2)^2+2c_1a_2c_2b_2=c_1^2+c_2^2+2c_1a_1c_2b_1+2c_1a_2c_2b_2=1+2c_1a_1c_2b_1+2c_1a_2c_2b_2>1$.

Comment: @user9976437 I edited my post

Comment: But the amswer is $\sqrt{c_1^2a_1^2+c_2^2b_1^2}|u_1>+\sqrt{c_1^2a_2^2+c_2^2b_2^2}|u_2>$, I thought AaronStevens posted a page about the states being non linear space but I don't konw where it went.

Comment: @user9976437 The information in my answer was true in general, but I was overlooking the specifics of your problem that this answer handles correctly. Therefore I removed the answer. This is the correct answer to your question. Also the solution you state in the comment above is the same solution expressed in this answer. Let me know if you can't figure out why. –